# Filling remaining height without JavaScript or flex

Tags: html, css

I have a page that uses some template with navbar and other components at the top.

I want to add a table that will fill the remaining height but not overflow vertically (add scroll to the table after).

The problem is that the given template did not use flex so I can't fill remaining height with flex. Right now I am using a JS function to calculate the remaining height then set the container div of the table to this height.

But is it possible to do it without JS?

Comment: Please show us the code in question.

Comment: No problem but I will add a sample asap (I can't copy the exact code because it's in an isolated system and copying exactly is very long but I can do the general layout)